# How to Order builds using Polyrepo

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

So I have a project set up as a polyrepo, meaning all services and libraries are in different repos.

Now, I've updated the service projects to reference the library project directly when using Debug as the build config in visual studio, and the package on NuGet when building in Release, on Azure DevOps.

The problem I am trying to solve is that my service builds sometimes fail when I've updated the library because the Library build hasn't completed and update NuGet yet.

What are my options here? Is there a way to ensure that the Library build completes first before the service builds start, or something similar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using the Release feature in Azure Devops, I suggest that you could  split the whole process into two stages (Library Build Stage and Service Build Stage).

For example:

[image: Stages]

These two stages are connected by `After Stage` relationship.

[image: Relationship]

Then when the Library Stage completes , the Service Build stage will start.

If the two stages need to specify different files in the build, you could select the target files in the `Visual Studio Build task -> Solution`.

By the way, if `Service Build stage` needs to use the build results of `Library Build stage`, I suggest that you can use the same [Self-hosted agents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/agents?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser#install) to run the release.

You can define it in `Tasks -> Agent Job -> Demands`.

[image]

**Updates:**

Since the Service Build and Library Build are two pipelines, you could try the following steps to order the Build running Step.

Step1: Set the [CI trigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/azure-repos-git?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#ci-triggers)(continuous integration) in Library Build. This could make sure the commits could trigger the Library Build.

Step2: Disable the CI trigger in Service Build. Then Set the [Pipeline trigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/pipeline-triggers?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) in Service Build. You could set the Library Build  trigger the Service Build.

In this case, you could make sure that the Service Build will run after the Library Build.

Comment: Hi, Yeah, this isn't exactly what I'm looking for. I'm not using the Release feature, I'm using pipelines. The scenario is that I'm pushing new commits to the Library and service projects then both pipelines on Azure DevOps will be triggered. The issue now is that the service build will fail because the Library build has not completed and update NuGet yet.

Comment: @GeradeGeldenhuys Thanks for your information. You could check the update. Please try to set the Pipeline trigger in Service Build. This could make sure that the Service Build runs after the Library Build.